# How would I insert an integer into a list pile in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

Running `insert ls n` should return a list of piles from taking `ls` and inserting `n` so that either `n` has been added to the head of the first pile in `ls` whose previous head is greater than or equal to `n`, or if it doesn't exist, a new pile containing just `n` is added to the end of `ls`.
For example,

```
insert [[4]; [5]] 3 = [[3;4]; [5]]
insert [[2]; [6]] 4 = [[2]; [4;6]]
insert [[3]] 4 = [[3]; [4]]
```

Basically, I'm trying to use the sort helper function that appends to the list if the element is less than the first in the list, and then in that case to just return the rest of the list.

```
let rec insert ls n =
  match n with
    | [] -> [x]
    | y::ys -> if x < y then x::y::ys else y::insert x ys;;

let rec sort n =
  match n with
    | [] -> []
    | x::xs -> insert x (sort xs);;
```

Comment: Hi @tmanmanev and welcome to SO. Your question has some issues before someone can answer to it. What's the problem you're facing? (I guess your code is not working as intended but I can't now at first sight if it's an algorithmic one, a compiler one or something else). Why do we need the declaration of `sort n` in your code? This is not a minimal working example (MWE for future references). Try to format your code with some backticks, list items etc to make it more readable. And try to ask a real question, "fix my code" is like "teacher, it's bugging", nothing new under the sun ;-)

Comment: In addition to Lhooq's comment, since the definition of `patience` contains a call to `insert`, a MWE would need to contain the definition of `insert` as well (or maybe you wanted to call another function there?)

Comment: I think `y::ys -> if x < y then x::y::ys else y::insert x ys` should instead be `(y::ys)::n' -> if x < y then (x::y::ys)::n' else (y::ys)::insert x n'`

Answer (score 2):

You keep confusing the order and type of arguments in your `insert` function. In your text description and following from the examples section, `insert` has type `'a list list -> 'a -> 'a list list`, but when you try to write your `insert` function, you match the element `n` with a list. In the same manner, when you call `insert` from `sort` you pass the element as the first argument.

Next, your insert function shall return a list of lists, but in the first branch of your match, `[] -> [x]`, you return just a list. In addition, there is no `x` variable bound in this match or anywhere else, probably you meant `n`?

Finally, when you compare the first element of the input list with the element `n` you compare the whole pile, instead of the head of the pile.

So let's try to rectify these problems, first of all, we have to match on `ls` instead of `n`,

```
let rec insert ls n = 
  match ls with 
(*      ^^
     ls not n! *)
```

Next, if we have an empty input, then we need to return a list containing a single pile, where a pile is a list itself,

```
  | [] -> [[n]] (* a list containing a list with a single element `n` *)
```

Finally, when we match on the head of the input list, we have to keep in mind that the head is the list itself, i.e., a pile, so we need to unpack it as well,

```
  | (x::xs)::ys -> 
 (* ^^^^^^^ 
    here x is the head of the pile, and x::xs is the whole pile *)
```

and pack it back,

```
if n < x then (n::x::xs)::ys else (x::xs)::insert ys n
(*            ^^^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^
             extended pile      intact pile         *)
```

The next step would be to make the match complete, i.e., to think what to do when the pile is empty itself (could it be?) and what to do when `x` is equal to `n`.

Comment: It may be helpful to introduce the asker to `as` when you see patterns like: `y::ys -> if x < y then x::y::ys`.  Or for the OP, suggest in a situation like this: `y::ys -> if x < y then x::ls`

Comment: @Chris, I was thinking about it, and yes it is tempting, but I am afraid of overwhelming them with too much information.